# Why there is only one hop in the tracert?

Tags: ip, traceroute

I use the tracert to a remote server IP address:

```
C:\Users\lll>tracert 103.224.19.11

Track by up to 30 hops
The route to f1.FF-SALE.COM [103.224.19.11]:

   1 44 ms 44 ms 44 ms f1.FF-SALE.COM [103.224.19.11]

The tracking is complete.
```

there I get the information.

I have two questions:

1. Why there only one hop?
2. What's the meaning of `f1.FF-SALE.COM [103.224.19.11]`?  the `tracert` will query the IP's domain?  the domain I can not access too.

But I also can not nslookup the domain.

---

**EDIT-01**

I am very sure I am not as the same network as the tracing IP.

My computer use NAT converted my intranet IP(`10.211.55.5`) address to the `118.113.43.66`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained by Jens Link, usually a one-hop traceroute means the host is on the same network. Since in your case, it is higly unlikely, that means you probably have a proxy that respond in place of the real host.

For the name f1.FF-SALE.COM, yes it is a DNS name associated to the IP 103.224.19.11. You can actually use nslookup to find it:

Type:

```
nslookup
 set type=PTR
 11.19.224.103.in-addr.arpa
```

And you will get the answer:

```
 Non-authoritative answer:
 11.19.224.103.in-addr.arpa      name = f11.ff-sale.com
```

Answer (score 4):

If you only see one hop you are on the same network as the host you are tracing. Check the output of ipconfig on the host from where you are testing. The host name you are seeing is the reverse DNS entry for this IP. It does not have  to match with the name resolution from host name to IP address.

Comment: I am very sure I am not on the same network as the host I am tracing.

Answer (score 0):

Verizon is caching websites locally in their central offices. Essentially making a copy of Google, Amazon, Facebook available in one hop.